# Get animation status in microseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm animating transition of 36 000 colours in 18 seconds using JavaScript. When user presses a button, he should be notified on what colour the animation was at the point when the button has been clicked. However, JavaScript measures time in milliseconds, which basically means that if the user presses the button on t=10ms the animation will be on colour 20 and when he presses it on t=11ms the animation will already be on 22.

Is there a way to measure time in JavaScript more accurately? So for example, I can be able to tell that the button was pressed on t=10.5ms so the animation would be on colour 21.

Comment: What does it matter? No user can actually click that fast. It'll take several hundred milliseconds for a user to process the color on screen, make a decision and actually move their finger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer browser versions support [performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) which gives time

> measured in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond.

performance.now uses [DomHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) as the time value which has the following property

> The unit is milliseconds and should be accurate to 5 µs (microseconds).

```js
var t1 = performance.now();
var t2 = performance.now();
console.log('passed ' + (t2 - t1) * 1000.0 + ' microseconds');
```

A polyfill can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5438650) and the list of the supported browsers can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=high-resolution-time).

Here's a good [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now) on `performance.now` by Paul Irish

One thing to note here is that the browser usually renders the screen at 60 frames per second, or once every ~16.67 milliseconds, irrelevant of the page performing animations or not. This means that what you're trying to do probably isn't possible since, although JS code can run in less than a millisecond, animations will always be separated by at least those 16.67ms. Thus every ~32nd color will actually be displayed because you're trying to display 2 colors per 1ms.

To update the colors at the frame rate of your browser, use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

*Note*: The 60fps is most common but the browser will adjust to the refresh rate of the screen.

Comment: It would be nice to include the minimum browser support in here.

Comment: @Soviut thanks for the edit. I also added a link to the polyfill for older browsers.

Comment: Does javascript/jquery animation update faster than 1millisecond though? Or does the frame change only every 1 millisecond?

Comment: The browser renders 60 frames per second which means it updates the screen every ~16.67 milliseconds irrelevant of the website performing animations or not. You can get access to each of these frames with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). My answer shows you that its possible to measure time in less then milliseconds, but you should still understand that what you're trying to do might not be possible since, although code can run in less than milliseconds, animations will be separated by *at least* those 16.67ms